# Referencing EF 4.1 Objects with Sandcastle

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, sandcastle

Is it possible to reference the help file objects for Entity Framework 4.1 in Sandcastle so that I can use syntax such as:

```
<see cref="T:System.Data.Entity.DbContext"/>
```

in my xml comments and have it refer to the proper documentation?  Currently, when I use the Sandcastle Help File Builder, all references to the objects in EF 4.1 are not linked, even though the inheritance is recognized.  The only work-around I found was to use url references to the documentation on the MSDN site, but I haven't figured out how to do that for links that are generated by the tool, such as methods and properties which are inherited from the base .NET classes contained in the EntityFramework.dll file.  I also tried referencing this file as well as the System.Data.Entity class from SHFB, but none of those options worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what to do.  When I included the EntityFramework.xml file as one of the documentation sources in SHFB, it was able to resolve all the references.  Including the EntityFramwork.dll or setting a reference to EntityFramework in the References section of SHFB did not work.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue as you, and even after adding the xml file as a documentation source, either I'm generating a chm with the whole EntityFramework in it or no links to msdn work.